# Setting the title of a navigation bar inside a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, titlebar

Well in my app I have a navigation controller with a table view, and when pressing a button a tab controller opens. In its first tab, I want the title of the navigation bar to be set.

Here is an image of my storyboard just to make sure we undestand each other.

[image]

This is my code that supposed to be working. I had used this code, when trying to open a single view and not a tab controller and it was working properly. So I guess I must change something.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
        SkiCenter *myDetViewCont = [[SkiCenter alloc] initWithNibName:@"SkiCenter" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        myDetViewCont.ski_center = [centers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SkiCenterIds"] animated:YES];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:myDetViewCont animated:YES]; // "Pushing the controller on the screen"
        [myDetViewCont release]; // releasing controller from the memory
        myDetViewCont = nil;        
    }
```

Where `Skicenter` is the name of the class for my first tab and `SkiCenterIds` is the identifier of my tab controller in storyboard.

Code in `Skicenter`.m is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.navigationItem.title = ski_center;        
}
```

but I do not see any title. So what I have done wrong?
I have also tried this:

```
[self.navigationController setTitle:@"Live"];
```

or

```
self.title=ski_center;
```

the ski_center has value because it is printed out normally in the NSLog.

Comment: Are you using a tab bar controller within a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I don't know if you did't noticed but I got it work like this:

I assigned my tab bar Controller a new class.

I did the following:

add it to **app delegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *center;
```

add it to **mainmap.m**

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.center=[centers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and in **mytabbarcontroller.m**

```
  AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ski_center=delegate.center;

    self.navigationItem.title = ski_center;
```

Answer (score 39):

Simple!

```
[self.tabBarController setTitle:@"Title"];
```

Comment: The title  text disappears on switching between the viewcontrollers

Answer (score 18):

Adding on to ghostrider's solution, in the mytabbarcontroller.m self.navigationItem.title didn't work for me.  I have a NavigationController whose detail view is a TabController and this is what I have in my first tab implementation

```
self.navigationController.visibleViewController.title = ski_center;
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. My set up - UINavigationControllers inside UITabbarController (which is root view controller). Somehow, all other obvious solution did not work at all.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Nicely done. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

In **Swift 4** and above

```
self.tabBarController?.title = "Title"
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok just so you know, it's very bad practice to put a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController` - Apple recommends for good UI design that you only should ever put a `UINavigationController` inside a `UITabBarController` and not the other way round. Either way, you should be able to change the title from the `UITabBarController` like this;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:ski_center];        
}
```

That should work.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please have a look and see if that works.

Comment: It didn't work either. what do you suggest me to do? I tried this structure because from a table I want to open a tab menu and not the first screen that opens to be a tab.

Comment: If it was me, I would forget the tab view and just open up another table view with 1-5 different options that you would usually have on your tabs, then link each row to your new pages. Alternatively you can open up another viewcontroller and create some buttons on it, again linking each button to your new pages. Both these solutions are better than the tab view controller for what you need it for. That way, the navigation controller can easily show titles and the process will make more sense to the end user.

Comment: This is a good advice and also make sense, thank you for pointing me to a right direction. Cheers

Comment: Can I get the reference link where Apple says that it is not good UI design to do this?

Answer (score 6):

In swift 3

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Your title goes here"
```

Answer (score 5):

I came across this and found a simpler solution. A new solution would be to change the navigation bar title from the landing view controllers like below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "title";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController;

 tabController.navigationItem.title = @"ABC";
```

This is working for me

From some R&D on internet

***You have to pass the navigationItem up the chain.
The UINavigationController shows the navigationItem belonging to its topViewController which is UITabBarController.
The UITabBarController shows the navigationItem titles in its tabs. So what you need to do is make sure that the tabBarController's navigationItem is it's selectedViewController's navigationItem***

So to recap:

> UINavigationController title = topViewController.navigationItem.title
>
> UITabBarController tabTitle =
>   selectedViewController.navigationItem.title
>
> UIViewController title = navigationItem.title

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[self.navigationController setTitle:@"Live"];
```